# Strange Azure VM performance Issues

Tags: azure, performance, windows-10, cpu-usage

We have 5 VMs on Azure for a customer. All VMs have been running smoothly.

Now since Monday the VM of one of the users is losing performance every day at 4 PM UTC+1 (+-1h). When we have these performance issues the CPU randomly runs at around 100%.

All other VMs are running smoothly while the software stack is exactly the same on all VMs.

We have been in contact with Microsoft Support for over 24 hours. In the meantime, we have been redeploying the VM 2 times, once out of a snapshot and once completely from scratch. The issue returns never the less.

All other VMs run under the same circumstances at around 5-30% CPU.

The issue is not reproducible at all. It just comes and goes for some hours at a time.

We now have four experienced engineers on this and we can not figure out the issue.

Do you guys have any idea what this could be? I’m glad for any input. We are soon going crazy here...

What we are running on the machines:

- O365 Office
- Adobe Reader
- Avast Antivirus
- Firefox / Chrome
- 2 specialized software tools for mechanics
- OneDrive
- ScreenConnect

What we already did to find out/fix the issue:

- Performance diagnostics (no specific process is causing it)
- compare Windows Versions
- compare all software installed
- compare all Azure settings
- recreated the VM from scratch
- check disk throughput
- check memory usage
- full AV check
- remove Veeam from all VMs due to suggestion from Microsoft support (SQL express got installed through Veeam)
- check all event logs -> nothing special

I’ll edit here when I remember more things we tried

Comment: Have you checked network utilization during issue?

Comment: "CPU randomly runs at around 100% CPU". Sure you can watch the cpu usage and find out the process that's causing that? If it happens every day at 4 pm that might be  a clear sign of scheduled job?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev we did check network utilization, but it turned out nothing.   
See my answer below for a full report on what caused the problem.

Comment: @JurajMartinkawe also checked that, but since the VM was new it kind of was out of place, and see there, nothing was scheduled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to our lovely friends over at Reddit, I've been able to find a solution to this. So we are running Burstable VMs (B-Series) and it got pointed out to me that these have a "burst quota over time".

After digging into this, I was able to find out that this hint was perfectly on the money. I knew that these VMs were burstable but I didn’t know about how this was measured or limited.

After a lot of digging and verifying assumptions using azure monitor with both the CPU percentage as well as the “CPU Credits Remaining” metrics on all the VMs it has shown that the CPU Credits were running out, so the CPU was capped at 40% till either the load reduced or credits have been accumulated.

When stoping and deallocating the VM the credits will be reset to a baseline and the credits were never used up until the customer finished working on it.

Thank you so much for getting me in the right direction, this saved us a lot of further trouble.

We have now pushed the size up by one and it has been running perfectly fine and credits don‘t go anywhere to zero.

This was only starting to happen this week since we had the backup-job running on Monday and Tuesday, so CPU usage was higher around noon when the backup started and that brought the credits down at around 4 PM.

The rest of the week the increased monitoring and trying to provoke the issue with increased usage did cause the issue to happen over again but delayed.

Also in the process of analytics, we realized that this particular user was just doing a bit more at once, so CPU gets more often over the CPU baseline, which decreased CPU Credits even more.

About two hours after we figured this out, Microsoft got to the same conclusion.

Thanks, everyone for their inputs, especially the Reddit user /u/VTi-R, I really appreciate it!

You can go and findout more about B-Series VMs here https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/introducing-b-series-our-new-burstable-vm-size/